Use Function from Shared Class as Inline Expression
I'm trying to use a function that lives in a shared Class with an inline expression on a web page. If the function lives in the code-behind-page, I can get it to work in multiple ways. However, this function lives in another Class and I cannot get it to use it directly. See my example and attempts below.
Here's the function from the shared Class.
Public Class Class1
    Public Function MyClassFunction() As String
        Return "Return results from MyClassFunction."
    End Function
End Class

I want to use the function on my web page as an inline expression. I understand what I show below won't work (I didn't declare a new instance of the class) and am just providing as an example of what I'm trying to do.
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_default" %>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <p>I want to use the function from the class as an inline expression:</p>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Class1.MyClassFunction() %>" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>

I've tried declaring a new instance of the Class in the code-behind-page and then tried using the various types of inline expressions, but none worked (e.g. embedded code block <% %>, display <%= %>, and data-binding inline expressions <%# %>).
Declared the shared class:
Public Class _default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim MySharedClass1 As New Class1
End Class

Examples of inline expressions used:
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%= MySharedClass1.MyClassFunction() %>" />
<asp:FormView blah blah blah ... has binding datasource ... blah blah blah>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%# MySharedClass1.MyClassFunction() %>" />
</asp:FormView>

I've also tried using an expression builder based on an old example I found (link below). Again, this works if the function is in the code-behind-page, but it doesn't work if it's in a shared class.
The class for the expression builder:
Imports System.CodeDom
Imports System.Web.Compilation
<ExpressionPrefix("Code")> _
Public Class CodeExpressionBuilder
    Inherits ExpressionBuilder
    Public Overrides Function GetCodeExpression(entry As BoundPropertyEntry, parsedData As Object, context As ExpressionBuilderContext) As CodeExpression
        Return New CodeSnippetExpression(entry.Expression)
    End Function
End Class

Web.config file reference for the expression builder:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <expressionBuilders>
        <add expressionPrefix="Code" type="CodeExpressionBuilder" />
      </expressionBuilders>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>

Declared the shared class (same as above):
Public Class _default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim MySharedClass1 As New Class1
End Class

Using it as expression builder inline expressions (<%$...%>):
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%$ MySharedClass1.MyClassFunction() %>" />

Link to blog post example:
Expression Builder Blog Link

Did you call DataBind() in Page_Load?

Not sure what you mean here? The databind is not always relevant, and in this example specifically there are no data bind controls.

I'm not sure what you mean by "shared class", but I would normally think of trying to indicate the VB equivalent of a C# static class (which in VB I think can only be spelled Module).

You of course have to create an instance of the class before you can use it, and hence that tends to take the choice of using a in-line expression off the table.
However, you can thus/then certainly create an instance of that class for the given page.
Also, keep in mind that in markup, you can't use a server-side expression for server-side controls (since they are ALREADY a server-side control).
So, say in the page, I place this code at the top to expose a public instance of that class:
Public MyClass1 As New Class1

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


End Sub

Ok, so now in markup, this is legal:
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>

        <h3><%=MyClass1.MyClassFunction %></h3>

    </div>
</form>

But this is NOT legal:
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
            Text='<%=MyClass1.MyClassFunction %>' >
        </asp:Label>

So, as above shows, you still need an instance of that class created before you can use it.
However, you can add/use what are called a "static" functions/methods in a class. As such, these class members can be used without having to create an instance of the class.
In fact, unlike C#, in VB.NET we can continue to use a code module. A code module is really much the same as a class with static methods.
Thus, any static (shared) code placed in that class becomes a global function.
So, either the choice of a code module, or that of a class with static (shared) code is a fine choice. Just keep in mind that for such static methods, NEVER scope pubic variables to the class, since in web land, due having one computer, then all (other) users will see the same values. So, yes to using static methods, but a huge big no (never) to use public variables exposed in that class. This includes exposing private variables scoped to that class (do not do this!).
I suggest for such shared library type of code, then often I don't bother with a class, and simply use a good old fashioned code module, and place such code in that module.
However, let's change the class function to static (shared) like this:
Public Class Class1

    Public Shared Function MyClassFunction() As String


        Return "Return results from MyClassFunction"

    End Function

End Class

Now, we don't have to create an instance of the class to use that shared code.
Hence, we can now remove our pubic instance of the class from the code behind, and now directly use the base class instance in the markup (server side) expression.
Hence, now code behind is this:
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


End Sub

And markup is now this:
        <h3><%=Class1.MyClassFunction %></h3>

Hence, we are directly using the base class, and no need exists to create an instance of the class before using as such. As I pointed out, you can also in place of a class + static (shared) methods, you can just create a good old fashioned code module like we did in the old VB4, 5, 6 and even VBA days.
So, just keep in mind that server-side expressions can't be used for controls that are already tagged as "runat=Server", since such code can be placed in the page load event anyway, and now we don't have 2 or 3 different ways to deal with setting control values, and thus creating a huge challenge for development and debugging (since we now don't have 2 different places to look for code when dealing with server-side controls). So, as a FYI, the server-side controls don't allow server-side expressions "%=". However, data binding is a VERY different matter, and server-side controls do allow data binding expressions (such as one would use in a GridView like %#).
So, assuming you wanted to set that label to the class result?
Hence this markup:
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="">
        </asp:Label>

Then we would be forced to use code behind, and as noted, we can't use a server-side expression for the Text attribute above (but then again, we don't have to do we???).
And then with our static (shared) code, then page load becomes this:
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Label1.Text = Class1.MyClassFunction

End Sub

So, once again, note how no instance of the class is required for the function to be used.

Thanks for your response. I want to key in on where you stated a few times "you can't use a server-side expression for server-side controls" (the rest was understood). Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't believe that is true. As I show in my last example, I found a post that uses a user-defined/custom "expression builder". It works with server-side controls, but the only issue is that it doesn't not work when referring to a function from a shared class.

Look closely, they are calling  %$ an expression   but it's limited to ONLY references to the configuration files,  not that $ allows general code expressions. For general %= which is a code turned into a response write, then %= can't be used.  %$ is not for general code but ONLY for grabbing configuration values- so that's legal,  but $ doesn't run code- only grabs configuration values and is a vast different than %= which is general code function values sent as response write.  So %$ is different than %=. They call it an expression builder,  but it's not a code/function calling operation
